# elements order in matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I need to find all elements in matrix and return only the first appearance of this element, in the order in which he stood in the word.
This what I did, but this code return all appearance of the elements in the matrix:

```
import math

letters = "UIPLAIFPEULU"
word = "FLU"

n = math.ceil((math.sqrt(len(letters))))

matrix  = [[char for char in letters[i * n: (i + 1) * n]] for i in range(n)]
elements = [x for x in word]



# print(matrix)
for i in range(len(elements)):
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for elem in range(len(matrix[row])):
            if elements[i] == matrix[row][elem]:
                print([row, elem])
```

My result:

```
    [1, 2]
    [0, 3]
    [2, 2]
    [0, 0]
    [2, 1]
    [2, 3]
```

How it must look:

```
[1, 2]->[0, 3]->[0, 0]
```

Comment: Could you explain more of what you want? It should output the index of letters in `word`, or the index of their appearance in `letters`? Give another example maybe?

Comment: It should output the index of letter in matrix. It means we took first letter from the word and look it index in the matrix. 
For example:
matrix = [['Q','W','E','B'],
                ['T','R','Y','U'], 
                ['O','B','Y','N']]
word = "TURBO"
the code must output:
[1,0]->[1,3]->[1,1]->[0,3]->[2,0] = [T]->[U]->[R]->[B]->[O]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `enumerate()` to keep a track of the number of times a letter appears. Your code didn't account for multiple occurrences which is why your output was different than what is expected.

Try:

```py
import math

letters = "UIPLAIFPEULU"
word = "FLU"

n = math.ceil((math.sqrt(len(letters))))

matrix  = [[char for char in letters[i * n: (i + 1) * n]] for i in range(n)]
elements = [x for x in word]


output = []
for element in elements:
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        if element in row:
            index = row.index(element)
            output.append([i, index])
            break
# List out items in output, separated by ->
print("->".join(str(x) for x in output))
```

Testing:

```py
letters = "SHERLOCKHOLMES"
word = "MEH"
```

Gives the output:

```py
[2, 3]->[0, 2]->[0, 1]
```